# How to change the specific checkbox label class @change in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Background:  I have a  list of checkboxes that is bound to a names array.  I am trying to change the class of the specific name once the checkbox is clicked.

Problem:  Once a checkbox is clicked it changes the class of all the names instead of the specific name attached to the checkbox.

JSFiddle of the issue:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg61Ldr5/73/)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<ul>
 <li v-for="name in names" :key="index">
   <input @click="available = !available" type="checkbox">  
   <label :class="{available:available}" >{{name.name}}</label>
  </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Vue instance

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    available: false,
    names: [{'name':'Jerry'},{'name':'Eddie'},{'name':'Kerry'},{'name':'Jane'}]
  }
})
```

Css

```
.available{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: You need to track an available state for each name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad the available variable to each name object and use a method to update the available property:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    names: [
      {'name':'Jerry', 'available': false},
      {'name':'Eddie', 'available': false},
      {'name':'Kerry', 'available': false},
      {'name':'Jane', 'available': false}
     ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateAvailable(index) {
      // Update the available property on the specific object with its index
      this.names[index].available = !this.names[index].available
    }
  }
})
```

Then in your template, call the method updateAvailable:

```
<div id="app">
<ul>
 <li v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index">
   <input @click="updateAvailable(index)" type="checkbox">  
   <label :class="{available: name.available}" >{{name.name}}</label>
  </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just pass `name` into the `updateAvailable` method? Then you won't need to look it up by index

Comment: @Phil you beat me to the punch. When passing name is doesn't work.  I am trying to figure out why myself

Comment: @EddieWeldon the method would need to become `updateAvailable(name) { name.available = !name.available }` but other than that, it should work

Comment: Exactly, to update the `name.available` property without using the element's index, you can pass the `name` object directly in the @click event, and update its available prop as @EddieWeldon explain.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `available` property in to each `name` element and toggle `name.available` in your template. You can even use `v-model` on your checkboxes.

```js
const names = [{'name':'Jerry'},{'name':'Eddie'},{'name':'Kerry'},{'name':'Jane'}]

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    names: names.map(name => ({ ...name, available: false }))
  })
})
```

```css
.available {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(name, i) in names">
      <input :id="`name_${i}`" v-model="name.available" type="checkbox">
      <label :for="`name_${i}`" :class="{ available: name.available }">
        {{name.name}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```